# When do you pluralize a noun that refers to multiple words in a list?

Tags: grammatical-number

I just read a sentence that ended with “... why a host might use two rather than one address.” and it seemed awkward to me. What rule governs a word's plurality, when it is used in this sort of shorthand to refer to both single and multiple things?

I would probably say:

> this or that *address*
>   these or those *addresses*
>   one or two *addresses*
>   two or one *addresses*

That last one is awkward and I wouldn't normally use it, but the “rather than” construction forces that order.

So do you pluralize if the last item is multiple? If there are any multiple items in the list?

Comment: I'd eliminate the awkwardness by rewording it to "two [nouns] rather than one."

Comment: Yeah, I would too, and I don't know why the editor of this book didn't. But I'm curious whether there's a standard answer if you do it the awkward way.

Comment: @zeugma I'd use 'pluralise'. It doesn't sound awkward. (I wouldn't normally leave this unqualified, but as you do ...).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It sounds extremely awkward to me. It's akin to abominations like "finalize" and "prioritize," ugly and unnecessary.  In addition, as an American, I spell it with a "z".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's just a British/American variation. ([Or just a variation.](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/03/ize-or-ise/))

Comment: @zeugma It sounds like you learned a new word! Feel free to use it or not. Any thoughts on the substance of my question?

Comment: [Purdue Owl](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/) has 'When a compound subject contains both a singular and a plural noun or pronoun joined by or or nor, the verb should agree with the part of the subject that is nearer the verb.

The boy or his friends run every day.
His friends or the boy runs every day.' / I'd always use the former here.  And this has been covered before on ELU. The 'rule' probably extends to 'two rather than one address', but I'd always choose 'two addresses rather than one' as John offers.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks! It would seem sensible to extend that rule from verb plurality agreement to noun plurality agreement, as you say.
If you'd care to put that in an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: @zeugma It sounds fine to me (now I'll qualify because you have done). There are almost 24 000 000 Google hits for the totally acceptable 'prioritize'.  In addition, I thought that as an American, you had and allowed freedom of speech. Including words and spellings that aren't your personal favourites.

Comment: Sorry; I don't want to seem to endorse a 'rule' I feel should be outweighed by Orwell's sixth: (vi) Break any ... rule ... sooner than say anything outright barbarous.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I just looked those up and I like them! To be precise, he apparently said “Break any *of these* rules ...,” but I agree with generalizing that idea.

Comment: To be precise, his name was Blair. If he can change his name, I feel I can amend his law (the tinkering shown by the ellipses) provided I don't change the underlying meaning.

Comment: All's fair in grammar and war!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the conjunctions "or" or "nor," the plurality depends upon the noun closest to the thing it modifies.  In your examples:

this or that address  (correct because "that" is typically singular); these or those addresses  (correct because "those" is typically plural); one or two addresses  (correct because "two" is plural); two or one addresses  (incorrect because "one" is singular)

Your original question, however, is not like the examples.  "... why a host might use two rather than one address" is a comparison between "two [addresses] rather than one address."  In the author's sentence, "address" is the correct choice.

Comment: Good answer, thanks.
I note that the author's choice would be correct by the proximity rule, too.

Comment: Goes without saying but this proximity notion also applies to verb number e.g. Neither the officers nor the shopkeeper lacks a credible defense.

Comment: The number of instances of "two rather than one address" on the internet, and those of "two rather than one dog / child / house / car" as compared with "two dogs / children / houses / cars rather than one",  seem strongly to indicate that the "two rather than one address" etc versions are unidiomatic. Arguing from an possible deletion does not license a form; usage does.